# Not able to connect to bitcoind on mac mini

Tags: bitcoind, mac, port

I'm running Bisq v1.6.1 on a iMac and that works fine using "use provided bitcoin Core nodes"
I also running a bitcoin core node on a mac Mini in the same local network on address 192.168.0.70

Putting this address in "Use custom Bitcoin Core nodes" and also checking this radio button does not work. The "Bitcoin network peers" stays at 0

The network in itself is working, as I can connect to the mini using the remote desktop

I found out that this issue is due to the fact that ports 8333 and 8332 are closed on the mac mini.

output from nmap

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8332/tcp filtered unknown

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8333/tcp filtered bitcoin
```

pf.conf looks like this:

```
pass in proto tcp from any to any port 8332
pass in proto tcp from any to any port 8333
```

Executed:

```
sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
sudo pfctl -E
```

Output from sudo pfctl -sr:

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pass in proto tcp from any to any port = 8332 flags S/SA keep state
pass in proto tcp from any to any port = 8333 flags S/SA keep state
```

My bitcoin.conf looks like this

```
# Bitcoin daemon
server=1
txindex=1

# Network
listen=1
listenonion=1
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
bind=127.0.0.1

# Connections
rpcuser=****
rpcpassword=****
rpcallowip=192.168.0.0/24
rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8332

zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333

peerbloomfilters=1
```

Also rebooting doesn't help